# Ignore missing values when creating dummy variable

Tags: variables, stata, dummy-variable

How can I create a dummy variable in Stata that takes the value of `1` when the variable `pax` is above `100` and `0` otherwise?
 Missing values should be labelled as `0`.

My code is the following:

```
generate type = 0
replace type = 1 if pax > 100
```

The problem is that Stata labels all missing values as `1` instead of keeping them as `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because Stata views missing values as large positive values. As such, your variable `type` is set equal to `1` when you request this for all values of `pax > 100` (which includes missings).

You can avoid this by explicitly indicating that you do not want missing values replaced as `1`:

```
generate type = 0
replace type = 1 if pax > 100 & pax != .
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the toy example below:

```
clear 

input pax
20
30
40
100
110
130
150
.
.
.
end
```

The following syntax is in fact sufficient:

```
generate type1 = pax > 100 & pax < .
```

Alternatively, one can use the `missing()` function:

```
generate type2 = pax > 100 & !missing(pax)
```

Note the use of `!` before the function, which tells Stata to focus on the non-missing values.

In both cases, the results are the same:

```
list

     +---------------------+
     | pax   type1   type2 |
     |---------------------|
  1. |  20       0       0 |
  2. |  30       0       0 |
  3. |  40       0       0 |
  4. | 100       0       0 |
  5. | 110       1       1 |
     |---------------------|
  6. | 130       1       1 |
  7. | 150       1       1 |
  8. |   .       0       0 |
  9. |   .       0       0 |
 10. |   .       0       0 |
     +---------------------+
```